# The "LIVE" badge on tvOS 15 UI

Tags: tvos

I learnt that tvOS 15's playback has a new red "LIVE" badge upon title view. The LIVE badge appears when the video is streaming.

However, how does it know the video is live streaming and manage to display the badge? Is the information which defines Live streaming included in metadata?

I watched [WWDC 21](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10191/) and read [an official document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/customizing_the_tvos_playback_experience#see-also) but couldn't find the answer.

[LIVE badge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lci45.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out this question by discussing with co-working engineers and reading the HLS document: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8216#section-4.3.2.6

It seems that there's a m3u8 tag `EXT-X-PLAYLIST`, which defines whether the content is LIVE.

If this tag has a specific event value doesn't have a value, it's defined LIVE.